# SQL VisualBasic 2010 View Result From table1 using table2 where id listview.item(0).text

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hello I need help `listview1` displays the contents of the table `Youtube` but if the table `viewed` are the same values​​, they will not be visible to the logged user where his `id` is `ListView2.Items(0).SubItems(0).Text` but will be visible to other users. How to do?

```
Table1(youtube)

    id  user    userlogin   url     
    1   22      12345       http/...1
    2   23      tommy       http/...2

Table2(viewed)

    user_id     site_id
    22          1     
    23          2

listview1

    id user url         userlogin 
    1  22   http:/...1 12345

listview2
    id
    22(user id)

ds = New DataSet
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from youtube where id not in (Select site_id from viewed) and user not in (Select user_id from viewed) where user=ListView1.Items(0).SubItems(0).Text", sqlcon) 
da.Fill(ds, "youtube")
lvDisplay.Items.Clear()
If ds.Tables("youtube").Rows.Count > 0 Then

    For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("youtube").Rows.Count - 1
        With lvDisplay.Items.Add(ds.Tables("youtube").Rows(i).Item(0).ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("youtube").Rows(i).Item(3).ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("youtube").Rows(i).Item(4).ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("youtube").Rows(i).Item(5).ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("youtube").Rows(i).Item(6).ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("youtube").Rows(i).Item(7).ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("youtube").Rows(i).Item(13).ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("youtube").Rows(i).Item(2).ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("youtube").Rows(i).Item(1).ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("youtube").Rows(i).Item(14).ToString)
```

please correction

http://obrazki.elektroda.pl/1681222700_1409155841.png

Comment: The title is as confusing as the whole question.

Comment: `"ListView1.Items(0).SubItems(0).Text"` is probably not anyone's name/ID

Comment: id is listview2 http://obrazki.elektroda.pl/1681222700_1409155841.png

Comment: but you are embedding `"ListView1.Items(0).SubItems(0).Text"` as a *literal* not the CONTENTS of the control and it will only ever work for the first LV item since it is hard coded.

Comment: look my infoimage http://obrazki.elektroda.pl/7720670300_1409162086.png

Comment: look at your SQL string, you are not using '53' or '34' or '123', you are using 'ListView1.Items(0).SubItems(0).Text'; I know in general what you are trying to do and I've told you 3 times the first thing that is wrong even thought you havent asked a clear question or posed a clear problem.

Answer (score 0):

resolved

```
"SELECT *FROM(youtube) WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT site_id FROM youtube INNER JOIN viewed ON youtube.id=viewed.site_id AND viewed.user_id WHERE user_id=" & ListView2.Items(0).SubItems(0).Text & ")"
```

Comment: since you asked the question yourself and solved it, please mark your answer as correct and try to give a small explanation about what how you fixed your problem, otherwise people might not gain insight on what you've done